# Node.js - rendering a undefined variable

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

Maybe the name of the title is wrong but I have a specific problem. The thing I want to do is to show possibilities of editing and deleting a post if a user is an admin. I have a local variable called currentUser that holds data specifically username, password, and role. This line of code works fine if the user is logged in but the problem that I have is when there is no data in local variable. if i give a statement if(currentUser == undefined or null) i still get a error and the site is not rendering(error that i get is role is not defined). Since I'm still new to this I believe currentUser data is coming from a middleware function from passport js. My question is how to render a page when currentUser is undefined.

Thanks in advance!

```
<% menu.forEach(function(menu){ %>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12 p-2 m-0 d-inline-block">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 22rem; ">
                        <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="<%= menu.pictureUrl %>" alt="Card image cap">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div style="height: 9rem;">
                                <h5 class="card-title"><%= menu.meal %></h5>
                                <div style="height: 4rem;">
                                    <p class="card-text"><%= menu.description %></p>
                                </div>
                                <div style="height: 4rem;">
                                    <p class="card-text"><strong><%=menu.price %>,00 Kn</strong></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <% if(currentUser.role == undefined){ %>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Stavi u košaricu</a>
                            <%} else if(currentUser.role === "admin"){ %>
                            <a href="/menu/<%=menu._id%>/edit" class="btn btn-warning">Uredi</a>
                            <div class="d-inline">
                                <form class="d-inline" action="/menu/<%=menu._id%>?_method=DELETE" method="post"><button
                                        class="btn btn-danger">Obriši</button></form>
                            </div>
                            <%}%>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <% }); %>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Are you sure this is where the error is coming from? Assuming `currentUser` is not `null` or `undefined` I would expect this code to work.

Comment: When i log in, there is data in local variable currentUser, and the site renders since it can read currentUser.role, so I belive it is a problem in that variable.

Comment: If you remove the `currentUser.role` stuff from your template, do you still get the error?

Comment: I've removed currentUser.role code, it runs fine. When its there it only doesn't work when user is not logged in.

Comment: I found what was the error and when I wrote if(currentUser == undefined || currentUser.role == "user") it worked. It seems that if I use currentUser.role as a first statement its a second level od undefined variable that cannot be reached. I don't fully understand this concept yet.